# Problem running ASP application on Service Account

Tags: authentication, asp.net

I'm having trouble running my ASP.NET application on a Service Account. I am using Windows Authentication. If I run it on the default Network Service account, I get authenticated in the background just fine, but when I switch to a custom service account, it prompts me over and over for credentials and finally throws a 401 error, even when I give credentials for a domain account in the local administrators group. I followed the How To [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649309.aspx) as best I could. If I turn off Windows Authentication and select allow anonymous access, it doesn't prompt for credentials, but gives me a 401 error. My application is installed on the D: drive and when I ran the aspnet_regiis.exe utility, I compared the permissions in C:\inetpub\wwwroot to the folder on the D: drive and added anything that was missing. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Is your domain account in the IIS_IUSR (for IIS7) or  IIS_WPG (for IIS6) group?

Check NTFS permissions of your folder (D:).
Does IIS_IUSR and IUSR accounts have NTFS read permission to D:?